# How to put 20b model on single gpu with deepspeed offload

Tags: pytorch, torch

Im trying to start inference G[PT NEOX](https://github.com/EleutherAI/gpt-neox) on single a100(40gb) gpu with deepspeed zero offload(https://www.deepspeed.ai/tutorials/zero-offload/), i know its possible to use it on training, but any solution to use it on inference?